# How to get data "out of" d3.xml(...)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, d3.js, javascript-objects

I use `Array.push()` inside a `d3.xml` function to gather some data from a xml.
But it doesn't seem to work, my `Array.length` = 0 whereas the `console.log` SHOWS ME that my data are here...

You can see it from yourself in this example in which I reproduce the phenomena, and give log details :

```
function extractXMLdata(ficXML) {
//  I want to put xml details in myObjects...
var myObjects = [];
/**
    Let's say mx xml file has 6 nodes with the attributs id, name and color
    I want to create 6 objects with these information
*/
d3.xml(ficXML,
    function(error, documentFragment) {
        /**
        I created a loop to simulate the part where I gather information from the xml...
        */
        for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
            var singleNodeData = {};    //   let's put node data in this object
            singleNodeData.id = 'ID_'+i;
            singleNodeData.name = 'fakename_'+Math.random();
            singleNodeData.color = 'color_'+Math.random();
            console.log(singleNodeData);
            myObjects.push(singleNodeData) ;
            if (i==5) console.log('How many objects in myObjects while I use "push"'? -> "+ myObjects.length);}
        }
    }
);
console.log(myObjects);
console.log("How many objects in myObjects ? -> "+ myObjects.length);

                /**     HERE IS THE LOG I GET
             []                                                                                                 aspocD3XML.js (ligne 28)    mmm, ok why not...
            How many objects in myObjects ? -> 0                                                                aspocD3XML.js (ligne 29)    wait, WTF ?
            Object { id="ID_0",  name="fakename_0.04496411033170611",  color="color_0.4732144810575395"}        aspocD3XML.js (ligne 20)
            Object { id="ID_1",  name="fakename_0.07845324609294535",  color="color_0.5036451388293461"}        aspocD3XML.js (ligne 20)
            Object { id="ID_2",  name="fakename_0.7121437976123653",  color="color_0.5682346193903798"}         aspocD3XML.js (ligne 20)
            Object { id="ID_3",  name="fakename_0.9415245332085834",  color="color_0.7830945674862615"}         aspocD3XML.js (ligne 20)
            Object { id="ID_4",  name="fakename_0.051691757268447436",  color="color_0.06430780013247395"}      aspocD3XML.js (ligne 20)
            Object { id="ID_5",  name="fakename_0.3813858899007565",  color="color_0.14585780574691742"}        aspocD3XML.js (ligne 20)
            How many objects in myObjects while I use "push" ? -> 6                                             aspocD3XML.js (ligne 22)    That's what I'm expecting !!!
            */
```

}

I suspect, regarding the order in which lines appears in the console, that this is because "d3.xml" part is executted after the rest (due to xml loading).
Anyway, I have no clue on how to work around this, and I HAVE TO get those objects out of extractXMLdata function (can't do all in d3.xml function)

Any Idea ?

Thanks very much...

Comment: ok, asynchronicity... that's what I should have been looking for...
Still, I am not at all familiar with d3, 
is it d3.xml that is a asynchronous function ?
Where am I supposed to assign a callback function in this example ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, `d3.xml` is async.  `function(error, documentFragment)` is the callback function.  `myObjects` will only be populated and available in that callback.

Comment: Considering the fact that I can't do something like 'var myObjects= d3.xml(...);' , how can I access the data, then ? Is there a way of using the d3.xml in a synchronous way ? or an equivalent function ?

Comment: You just place *all the code* that needs to use `myObjects` inside the callback.

Comment: Disregard, guys !
At last, I understand that I don't need d3.xml for this purpose, I will use  'document ' properties. 
I'll get back to this asynchronicity thing later. I'm a javascript newbie but I like it, so I suppose I won't escape facing this :)
Thanks for you help !